# A question about the proof of fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, proof-explanation

I'm reading the proof of *fundamental theorem of algebra* from textbook *Analysis I* by Amann.

> [image]
>
> [image]

I have a problem understanding the part:

> Hence we can write $q$ in the form $$q=1+\alpha X^{k}+X^{k+1} r$$ for suitable $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}^{ \times}, k \in\{1, \ldots, n-1\}$ and $r \in \mathbb{C}[X]$.

I'm unable to see how we write $q$ in such form. Could you please elaborate in this issue? Thank you so much!

Comment: $q(0)=1$. The next nonzero term is $aX^k$, and the other terms form $X^{k+1}r(X)$.

Comment: Oh I got it. Thank you @LordSharktheUnknown@ Could you write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it and close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$q(X)=1+b_1X+b_2X^2+\cdots+b_nX^n$$
with $b_n\ne0$. Maybe $b_1=0$ or even maybe $b_1=b_2=0$. In any case there
is a **first** $k$ with $b_k\ne0$. Let $a=b_k$, so then
$$q(X)=1+aX^k+b_{k+1}X^{k+1}+\cdots+b_nX^n.$$
Note that we can have $k=n$, contrary to the textbook's insistence that
$k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$. Rewrite this as
$$q(X)=1+aX^k+r(X)X^{k+1}$$
where
$$r(x)=b_{k+1}+b_{k+2}X+\cdots+b_n X^{n-k-1}.$$